# How to get data from specific row in table ng2 smart table

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

I'm working on ngx-admin in ng2 smart table I added a custom button that open model 
I want to pass data where the button exist

**this is table settings**

```
settings = {
    actions: {
      add: false,
    },
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="nb-plus"></i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="nb-edit"></i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="nb-checkmark"></i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="nb-close"></i>',
      confirmSave: true,
    },
    delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="nb-trash"></i>',
      confirmDelete: true,
    },
    columns: {
      _id: {
        title: "ID",
        type: "number",
      },
      nameUser: {
        title: "nameUser",
        type: "string",
      },
      contactName: {
        title: "contactName",
        type: "string",
      },
      phone: {
        title: "phone",
        type: "number",
      },
      email: {
        title: "E-mail",
        type: "string",
      },
      role: {
        title: "role",
        type: "string",

        editor: {
          type: "list",
          config: {
            selectText: "Select the Location to see options...",
            list: this.roles,
          },
        },
      },
      city: {
        title: "city",
        type: "string",
      },
      postCode: {
        title: "postCode",
        type: "string",
      },
      registerAddress: {
        title: "registerAddress",
        type: "string",
      },
      address: {
        title: "address",
        type: "string",
      },
      bindedGroup: {
        title: "bindedGroup",
        type: "string",
      },
      tid: {
        title: "tid",
        type: "string",
      },
      bindedSn: {
        title: "bindedSn",
        type: "html",
        valuePrepareFunction: (cell, row) => {
          console.log(row.bindedSn);
          this.bnsn = row.bindedSn;
          return row.bindedSn;
          // console.log(row);
        },
      },
      bindedTime: {
        title: "bindedTime",
        type: "string",
      },
      longitude: {
        title: "longitude",
        type: "string",
      },
      latitude: {
        title: "latitude",
        type: "string",
      },
      localisation: {
        title: "localisation",
        type: "string",
      },
      openModal: {
        title: "openModal",
        type: "custom",
        renderComponent: NbListComponent,
      },
    },
  };
```

**ButtonComponent**

```
export class NbListComponent implements OnInit {


 

  constructor(private dialogService: NbDialogService) {}

  

  ngOnInit() {
 
  }

  openModal() {
    this.dialogService.open(AffectTPEComponent, {
      closeOnBackdropClick: true,
    });
  }

  
}
```

as shown at last column there is a button that open a modal , by clicking on the button I want to pass bindedSn data of it's row .

NB: tableComponent and modalComponent are not linked as parent and child